# How to run gulp after "docker-compose up"?

Tags: docker, gulp, docker-compose

Can you help with running gulp tasks inside the Docker container with `docker-compose`, so it would compile SCSS files?

My file structure at host machine:

```
/application
--/config
--/models
--/public
----/scss
----/css
----index.html
----gulfile.js
--/routes
.dockerignore
.gitignore
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
package.json
server.js
```

**/application/public/gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('./scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./scss/styles.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:6

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install nodemon -g && npm install bower -g && npm install gulp -g

RUN cd /app
RUN npm install
RUN cd /app/public && bower install  --allow-root
RUN cd /app

COPY . /app
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: nodemon /app/server.js
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/public
      - /app/config
      - /app/models
      - /app/routes
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    restart: always
```

Ideally, it would be good to run the command from the `docker-compose.yml` file to start watching **scss** files inside the `/application/public` folder, but I wasted couple of days to solve this problem.

Also, I tried to run gulp inside the container. Actually, it works ok, but changes were not reflected at host machine.

Please do not suggest to use ready-made Docker-Hub images. I have used them and they did not solve my issue.

I'll be thankful for any help, links, info or ready-solution.

Comment: Have you looked at setting up a separate service in your compose file with a shared codebase & shared volumes? One service would run gulp the other runs Node. This is how I run rails + background tasks.

Comment: this is a bad practice of running application and running gulp afetr it. And as you are running node application with the base node image. you can install gulp and copy and install all requirements and do docker-compose up

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate service in your compose file to run a separate command in a separate container (see the web line & the gulp service line below

```
version: '2'
services:
  web: &web
    build: .
    command: nodemon /app/server.js
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/public
      - /app/config
      - /app/models
      - /app/routes
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  gulp: *web
    command: <gulp command to watch files>
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    restart: always
```